# JArray with Type == JTokenType.Null

Tags: json.net

I want to create the JArray equivalent of `null`, that is a JArray where `jarr.Type==JTokenType.Null`

Is that possible ?

JArray does not have a `CreateNull` methos like JValue

I tried `JArray.Parse("null")` but that throws

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: Nul

Is there another way to do this ?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  In the [JSON standard](https://json.org/), `null` is a value while an array is an *ordered collection of values delimited by `[` and `]`*.  You can't have a null array vs a null object vs a null value.

Comment: ok got it if you post an answer I'll mark it

Comment: Can you describe more about what you are actually trying to do which has gotten you to the point of trying to parse a `null` into a `JArray`?